# Java for( x : y) execution

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop

I have the following for loop:

```
for(String s : someString.split("\\s+")){
   //do something
}
```

Does java execute the split() method each time the loop iterates, or does it do it only once and keep a temp array to iterate on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It only does it once, and uses that array and interates through it.

Edit: from Mat This is the [reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2)

Comment: Exactly what happens is detailed in the [JLS enhanced `for` statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2) doc

Answer (score 3):

It stores the array in a temporary variable before using it.

Answer (score 2):

No the split is executed once on the string and after that the loop iterate over the result

Answer (score 1):

The split method is only called once. Think of the structure (also known as a for-each) as follows:

- The second argument is evaluated and kept for the duration of the loop.
- If the argument gives an Iterable or is an array (special case), a check is then made to see if the type of the first argument corresponds with the elements that are returned.
- The process enters the loop and executes the code inside the scope and exits when there are no more elements left.

More information can be had here:
http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

P.S: This works with Java 5 minimum.

Comment: Also if by "an array is iterable" you mean that an array implements the `Iterable` interface, that's wrong.

Comment: Perhaps. It's difficult to say as an IDE like Eclipse does a form of compiling when it underlines issues.

Comment: @trutheality: What I mean is that the array would behave as an Iterable after unboxing. I'll admit this is an assumption though and I'd be interested to hear if Java actually handles this differently. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: "The Expression must either have type Iterable or else it must be of an array type, or a compile-time error occurs." - From the JLS reference posted by Mat

Comment: @James P. [this](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html) is how I understand it works: if the second argument is an array, the loop is interpreted as `for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)`, and if the second argument implements `Iterable` it uses the iterator for loop. Unboxing is a separate feature that can sometimes be conveniently combined with foreach in cases like `for( int n : list )` where `list` is an `Iterable<Integer>` for example.

Comment: That is correct. The for loop works differently on case basis according to whether it is supplied an `Iterable` or an array. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216768/does-unboxing-apply-to-arrays Now this brings the question of how an array is represented as there seems to be no Array class in the Javadoc.